# Not able to ask new question in Drupal Meta

Tags: support, bug

I want to ask a [**new question**](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) in [Drupal Meta](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/), but whenever I click the [Ask Question](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), it loads(Pre-filled) the fields with old question. See the below screenshot or check this recorded [gif file](https://user.iter.org/filesharing/?uid=df7c094b-6894-4caf-b8ff-979dc05b8520).

Note: I already submitted that [post](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2786/user-comment-loading-in-the-editor) yesterday, but don't know why it saved as draft.

> [image]

And also I faced a similar issue [here](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2786/user-comment-loading-in-the-editor) yesterday

Comment: Same answer to the other question you mentioned. Drafts get saved, whether it is a question or an answer. Discard the draft and you are good to go.

Comment: @Antony It never happened before and if it loads every time with pre-filled fields for "Ask question" then it is not good.

Comment: @Antony I don't know why it is saved as draft, because it already submitted yesterday itself http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2786/user-comment-loading-in-the-editor

Comment: I blame caching.

Comment: @ColeJohnson caching in server-side or client-side ?, I made hard refresh ctrl+f5

Comment: Whilst this is to do with caching Cole, it's deliberate. A draft of your post gets saved on the server to help you out if your browser crashes etc.